# I want to group by month and get sum of amount from project embedded document

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

This is my mongo-DB database collection image
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TIKh1.png

I want to add query in which I need to get group by month and sum of (amount) from (project) array that is being embedded in (usermodel) collection

This is how i am currently doing it, but in console no output is showing

```
router.get('/calculatedata', Authenticate, async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const getUser = await UserModel.findById({ _id: req.userID });
        const getProject = await getUser.aggregate([
            {$unwind: '$project' },
            {$group: { _id: { month: "$month" },
                      total:{$sum:"$project.amount"}
                     }
            }]);
        console.log(getProject)
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(400).send({ message: "Something Went Wrong" })
    }
})
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You need to extract the month from date and extract the date from string first , example:

```
 month: {$month: { $dateFromString:{ dateString:"$project.date" , timezone:'America/New_York' }} }
```

or extract the month like number ( 01..12) from the string:

```
    month: {  $substr: ["$project.date", 5, 7]     }
```

Comment: But I am unable to get access to project embedded document .

Comment: How can i implement query on project document

Comment: after you $unwind the project array you can access the subdocuments with "." as shown above , also please, provide text documents example so it is suitable for processing further ...